# How to plot linear regression with two categorical predictors in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, regression, categories

I have a data-set that looks like this in its short version:

```
> means_RT

sNum    RealRatio   InstRatio   RT
3       0           0           358.9782
4       50          30          314.2908
5       30          30          330.7382
6       0           0           335.9542
7       30          50          327.9859
8       50          50          302.7551
9       30          30          326.9188
10      30          30          343.7648
11      0           0           384.5667
12      50          30          319.3677
13      30          50          358.409
14      30          30          300.7474
```

where **sNum** is the participant number, **RealRatio** and **InstrRatio** are categorical variables and **RT** (reaction time) is a numericle variable. I ran a regression model:

```
fit1 <- lm(formula = RT ~ RealRatio + InstRatio + RealRatio*InstRatio, data = means_RT)
summary(fit1)

Call:
lm(formula = RT ~ RealRatio + InstRatio + RealRatio * InstRatio, 
data = means_RT)

Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-85.206 -22.920  -0.381  21.107 105.713 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         333.807279   9.019529  37.009   <2e-16 ***
RealRatio             0.726752   0.476883   1.524    0.131    
InstRatio            -0.026615   0.471673  -0.056    0.955    
RealRatio:InstRatio  -0.004032   0.015138  -0.266    0.791    

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 37.48 on 91 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06734,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.03659 
F-statistic:  2.19 on 3 and 91 DF,  p-value: 0.0946
```

And I have also tried to plot the regression but I failed:

```
ggplot(means_RT, aes(x= RealRatio, y=RT,  fill=InstRatio)) + 
  geom_bar(binwidth = 1.5, alpha = .5, position = "identity")
```

How should I plot linear regression with two categorical predictors: **RealRatio** and **InstRatio**?

Comment: What is it that you would like to show?

Comment: interaction between RealRatio and InstRatio in terms of RTs